# Using D programming language in a .NET context

Tags: .net, interop, d

I'm curious: has anyone used D together with .NET languages? Is that even possible? What kind of stuff is easier/makes sense to do in D that's hard to do in, say, C++/CLI?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Using D together with .NET is very possible.
The reason:

- .NET is able to import unmanaged C libraries (.dll's which export C functions) using the [dllImport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute(VS.71).aspx) attribute.
- D is able to export C functions. using the [export](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/1.0/attribute.html#ProtectionAttribute) and [extern (C)](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/1.0/attribute.html#linkage) attributes

So the considering the technicalities, it's completely possible.

With regards to what D makes easier than C++, the answer is fairly easy: "Everything".
In a sense, D is really just a copy of C++ with just about everything done simpler. Sure that's only a half story, but reasonably true.

Answer (score 6):

http://the-free-meme.blogspot.com/ is a blog by someone who is working on getting d on dot net.

Edit:

[nanu](http://dsource.org/projects/nanu) and [nono](http://dsource.org/projects/nono) are projects that are trying to get mono/D working but both have not had any changes in there svn /trunk in the last year.

Answer (score 3):

You can call a D DLL by creating a [DLL with a C Interface](http://www.d-programming-language.org/dll.html), and then calling it via P/Invoke from .NET.

Answer (score 2):

There is also [D for .NET](http://dnet.codeplex.com/) which is a way of compiling D code right to [CIL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language).

The other answers are correct in that sharing code with the native implementation is easy too.

Answer (score 1):

I believe D can call .NET assemlies visible via COM: http://wiki.dlang.org/COM_Programming.