# Where to get D for .Net

Tags: .net, d

Where can I get D for the .Net framework?

Answer (score 3):

(Heavily edited.)

Assuming you mean [D the programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D_programming_language), you can't currently do so. The currently released D compilers compile to native code, not managed code. A port is in progress, and  this [recent InfoQ interview](http://www.infoq.com/news/2009/03/D-NET) which may be of interest for more information.

[This existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/539234/using-d-programming-language-in-a-net-context) has other information and links.

Comment: There is a work-in-progress D compiler for the .NET platform.

Comment: Ooh... that'll be interesting. I was under the impression that it had various features which wouldn't really work for a managed environment... but then there's C++/CLI, so...

Comment: I was gonna say that .. if there's a C++.Net then why the hell is D.Net not possible??

Comment: It's not that you can't make it work. It's just that there are a few points that end up being a Cast iron SOB to get right. see: http://the-free-meme.blogspot.com/ for more details

Comment: @Ctrl Alt D-1337: Even the edited answer? Are you saying there *is* a version which is ready to be used right now?

Comment: No I was talking about the original answer otherwise everybody is correct as long as they eventually edit.

Comment: So did you downvote the *existing* answer on the basis of what was *originally* there, despite the current answer being informative?

Comment: I don't find the current answer informative. I've read that article and I'm already aware of http://the-free-meme.blogspot.com/ http://dsource.org/projects/nanu http://dsource.org/projects/nono

Comment: Mind if I add those links to the answer? And while it may not be informative to *you* (already knowing about those things) don't you think it's informative to the OP?

Comment: Those links I gave are not so informative if he had searched: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/539234/using-d-programming-language-in-a-net-context .

Comment: Right - that's definitely a more useful one.

Comment: what's the point of keeping the original answer?? which is wrong anyway

Comment: I've edited it heavily - although I wouldn't say the original answer was actually wrong, in terms of the options the OP has available today. Can he get D for the .NET framework? I don't think so, today. Of course, more information is good, hence the edit...

Answer (score 2):

Are you referring to this?

[D.Net Release Version 1.0.0.](http://ddotnet.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=6306#ReleaseFiles)

Comment: Are you contradicting Jon Skeet?!?!?!?!?!?!?!?!

Comment: "D.NET (DDotNet) is a "Development for .NET" framework, created to help all developers to create a better applications.
Contains a implementation of ORM (Object Relational Mapping) framework with Business Objects Framework and other components."

I don't think this is what the OP was looking for.

Comment: I agree with CyberShadow, but it is a fine answer for a vague question.

Comment: has nothing to do with D, just accidental similarity in name

Comment: I think that make 4 or 5 different D's

Comment: @BCS - I think Stroustrup said in D&EC++ that there were already a dozen or so languages called D when he started on C++.

Comment: I am in no way contradicting Jon Skeet. I posted before him and was unaware that his answer would conflict with mine.

Comment: The two don't even really contradict each other - they're just interpreting the question differently.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working on a D .net compiler implementation, it is not ready for public release just yet, and it will not support the Phobos and Tango libraries in the first release (just the core language).

Answer (score 0):

There is a [D Compiler for .NET](http://dnet.codeplex.com/). It appeared just after this question so Jon Skeet was not wrong after all.