# Using D Programming Language for .NET-Projects

Tags: .net, d

the same question has already been asked 2 years ago in
[Using D programming language in a .NET context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/539234/using-d-programming-language-in-a-net-context)
I want to bring up this issue again. 
Being a .NET-developer who is interested in using D instead of C++, what is the best solution to get access to the .NET framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any progress other than what is listed on that other question. OTOH LLVM based compilation has improved somewhat and I can find indications that there is a MSIL (a.k.a. .NET) back-end for LLVM, but I don't know what state it is in.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [D Compiler for .NET](http://dnet.codeplex.com/).