# Is it possible to use D from C# via P/Invoke?

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke, d

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using D programming language in a .NET context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/539234/using-d-programming-language-in-a-net-context)

Just curious, is it possible to use D from C# via P/Invoke? And if not, what other mechanisms are there to pass data between the two?

Comment: The duplicate was asked by the OP !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.d-programming-language.org/dll.html

If you can have it in win32 dll, you should be able to P/Invoke. Never tried it though...